# cant get output from stored procedure

Tags: ado.net

I have a message in exception:

> The formal parameter "@LoginHash" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

My database code:

```
      create table Account
       (
        Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,          
        Identifier INT NOT NULL,
         Passphrase INT NOT NULL
        );

        GO
          CREATE PROCEDURE Authenticate (@LoginHash INT, @PasswordHash INT, @Result BIT OUTPUT)
        AS 
      BEGIN TRANSACTION
    if ((select count(Identifier) from Account where (Identifier=@LoginHash and Passphrase=@PasswordHash))>0)
        set @Result=1
    else
        set @Result=0;

       COMMIT
        GO
```

My ado.net app code:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Authenticate", SqlCon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter par = cmd.Parameters.Add("LoginHash", SqlDbType.Int);
        par.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        SqlParameter par1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("PasswordHash", SqlDbType.Int);
        par.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        SqlParameter par2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("Result", SqlDbType.Bit);
        par.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;            
        var result = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();//exception there
```

How to fix it ?
I **changed the code** on the following:

```
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Text, SqlCon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter par = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginHash", (SqlInt32)loginHash);            
        SqlParameter par1 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PasswordHash", (SqlInt32)passwordHash);            
        SqlParameter par2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Result",SqlDbType.Bit);
        par2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

And now I have an error NullReferenceException() occured in the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're marking incorrect parameter as Output. Change last

```
par.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

To

```
par2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

And you don't have to mark others as Input, that's default.

Also I don't see where you actually pass actual values for these parameters, perhaps it's elsewhere, but just in case, here's a shortened version of your code that includes passing example values as well:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Authenticate", SqlCon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoginHash", 123); // example value for LoginHash
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PasswordHash", 456); // example value for PasswordHash
cmd.Parameters.Add("Result", SqlDbType.Bit).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
var result = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Stinks to copy & paste ;)

Comment: @Gonzix Happens to the best of us

Comment: Yup, not trying to be critic... par.Direction is set 3 times... Just that

Comment: Now I get error: Procedure or function 'Authenticate' expects parameter '@LoginHash', which was not supplied.   
Are there any inaccuracies in the code ? I checked it with loginHash -1334931363 and passwordhash -856103078.

Comment: This time it might be my copypasting. This shouldn't really matter, but can you try prepending param names with @, e.g. "@LoginHash" instead of "LoginHash" ?

Comment: Doh! I was blind as a bat. Since you're using ExecuteScalar you don't even need Output parameter - remove that from param declaration in C# code. Then in your SP declare `@Result` as a local variable and add as a very last line `SELECT @Result`